# Is it possible to change the message about registration being closed for an event?

Tags: civievent

Right now if you visit an event page before an event starts - it says

> Registration is closed for this event

Ideally it would say

> Registration is closed for this event and will open on December 5th at 12PM.

or

> Registration opens on December 5th at 12PM.

Anything indicating to come back essentially.

Answer (score 0):

The wording is [hardcoded](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.tpl#L16) in template file, you can change it by altering the template file or writing a JS or hook via extension to replace the wording.